# How to call an existing lambda via fast api deployed to aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, fastapi, asgi

I'm following an example of how to create an fast api and use magnum adapter and deploy the application as an aws lambda. I understand all of the fast api is zipped up and executed as an lambda. we can define routes ( sample code below) . in the following set up, can we set up an route to call an existing lambda function? or in other words, create a route that calls another lambda function?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Up and running!"}


handler = Mangum(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to invoke separate function directly with `boto3` for example: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/invoke.html

Alternatively, if your other function is running behind an API Gateway, you can *just* hit the endpoint that calls that function.

Note: If you need to synchronously call other Lambda functions from your function, you might run into cascading cold-start issues. What functionality do you want to build?